# Generating/validating checksums in a single line?

Tags: shell, checksum

When I generate checksums for my files, I have to do a bit of extra work to get them formatted properly:

```
CHECKSUM="$(shasum "$file" | cut -b 1-40)"
echo -n "$CHECKSUM" > "$file.sha"
```

This is to ensure that in the file, I only have the checksum itself (hence `cut`) and that at the  end of the file, there's no newline (hence `echo -n`).

Validating the checksums also requires a bit extra work:

```
CHECKSUM="$(shasum "$file" | cut -b 1-40)"
echo -n "$CHECKSUM" | diff - "$file.sha"
```

Is there an easier, more compact way of creating and validating checksums without storing the path? I prefer not to store the path in the checksum along with the file as it makes the files less portable IMO.

Comment: If you need the checksums for many files then it would be more efficient to run `sha1sum` over all files and make `awk` put each line in a single file: `sha1sum * | awk ...`

Comment: Would [md5deep](http://md5deep.sourceforge.net/) be helpful ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An obvious small improvement to

```
CHECKSUM="$(shasum "$file" | cut -b 1-40)"
echo -n "$CHECKSUM" > "$file.sha"
```

is:

```
shasum "$file" | cut -b 1-40 >"$file.sha"
```

The trailing newline by `cut` can be avoided with `awk:

```
shasum "$file" | awk -v ORS="" '{print $1}'
```

A simpler form of

```
CHECKSUM="$(shasum "$file" | cut -b 1-40)"
echo -n "$CHECKSUM" | diff - "$file.sha"
```

is:

```
if [ "$(shasum "$file" | cut -b 1-40)" = "$(<"$file.sha")" ]; then ...
```

Comment: `shasum "$file" | cut -b 1-40 > "$file.sh"` - Won't this append a newline at the end of the file by default?

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay I guess you misunderstand the meaning of `echo -n`. That does **not** mean "strip off all trailing newlines". It means: "Do **not** add a newline" I.e. if there is a newline at the end of `$CHECKSUM` then both your and my solution write a trailing newline to the file. But who cares about trailing newlines when using `$()`? `echo -n $CHECKSUM` would strip off newlines, though.

Comment: My files end up being 41 bytes rather than the expected 40 bytes - trailing newline.

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay Right. My `$CHECKSUM` explanation is correct but as `$CHECKSUM` does not appear in my code it is not helpful. But as the `"$(<"$file.sha")"` removes the newline this does not matter (unless you use the files in other ways, too). This problem can probably not be avoided wit `cut`. I will add an `awk` alternative to my answer.